# Jetpack Compose: ignoring descendants' content description

Tags: android, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose, talkback

Let's say I have a Column with Rows. Each Row is a logical unit and I want Talkback to navigate through the Column Row by Row, without selecting and descendants of the row. That's easily achievable with `mergeDescendants = true`

Now, I have a tailored contentDescription for the Row, that provides a more natural description. How do I ignore the descendant's text to be read, to prevent doubling the information?

tl;dr: When using `mergeDescendants`; how do I make Talkback replace rather than merge the descendants' contentDescriptions?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    // Goal: Each row is a single entity for talkback, that has a content desccription describing the entire tow
    // descendants should not be focused when navigating by swipe w/ talkback
    // "Greeting for Android X" should be read, descendants should not be read automatically.
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {// Screen padding
        Box(
            // "greeting for Android 1 ... Hello Android! ... How do you do?" :-(
            // descendants can not be selected individually :-)
            Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
                contentDescription = "greeting for Android 1"
            }
        ) {
            Row {
                Text(text = "Hello Android!", modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp))
                Text(text = "How do you do?", modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp))
            }
        }
        Box(
            // "greeting for Android 2" :-)
            // descendants will be traversed next :-(
            Modifier.semantics {
                contentDescription = "greeting for Android 2"
            }
        ) {
            Row {
                Text(text = "Hello Android!", modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp))
                Text(text = "How do you do?", modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp))
            }
        }
        Box(
            // "greeting for Android 3" :-)
            // descendants can not be selected individually :-)

            // When using tap to speak rather than swipe, it is hard to select the row:
            // Only when tapping empty space will the row be selected.
            // When tapping either text element,nothing happens. :-(
            // Expected: the row is selected and "greeting for android 3" is read when 
            // I tap anywhere inside it's bounds
            Modifier.semantics {
                contentDescription = "greeting for Android 3"
            }
        ) {
            Row(Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics {}) {
                Text(text = "Hello Android!", modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp))
                Text(text = "How do you do?", modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @nino-van-hooff, did you succeed? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 4):

I assume that in the code you presented above the top level `Box` represents your "rows". Try firstly merging semantic properties of Box's children and then clearing all of them and setting your custom content description by applying the following modifier to Box:

```
Modifier
  .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}
  .clearAndSetSemantics { contentDescription = "greeting for Android 1" }
```

Additionally, you could also explicitly call the following on each Box's children to ensure their semantic properties are ignored:

```
Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics {}
```

Comment: tapping the inner rows don't activate talkback.

Comment: Not true. Talkback reads inner items of a Column / Row (as well as LazyColumn / LazyRow) separately if you don't merge Column's / Row's items semantic properties. The above answer suggests to merge semantic properties of an item, not of the whole Column / Row.

Comment: `clearAndSetSemantics{}` works well for overriding the content description to be exactly what you need it to be. However, it clears all the other semantics. So buttons will no longer be clickable when retrieved by text in unit tests. It seems to be a trade off.